# Functions in Hilbert Spaces

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, mathematics

I'm trying to prove that given a function $\psi(x)$ defined non zero for $0\leq x\leq L$ s.t. $\int_0^L\vert \psi(x) dx\vert^2=1$, then it can be represented as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n\phi_n$ where $\{ \phi_n \}_{n=0}^{\infty}\subset\mathcal{H}$ is an orthogonal and complete basis and $a_n=\int_0^n \psi(x) \overline{\phi_n}(x) dx.$

Now, for anyone who is not familiarized with orthogonal/complete basis, here are some useful definitions:

Orthogonality: $\int_0^L \overline{\phi_n}(x){\phi_m}(x)=\delta_{mn}$ the Kroenecker Delta

Completeness: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\overline{\phi_n}(x){\phi_n}(x')=\delta(x-x')$ the Dirac Delta

My attempt includes adding the orthogonality condition given n=m but I have a conjugate $\psi$ hanging about. Can I get a hint on how to do it?

Comment: Well, what you're trying to prove is actually the definition of completeness for a set of elements in a Hilbert space. Your given definition of completeness cannot be given in a Hilbert space because the Dirac delta is not part of a Hilbert space and you'd need additional structure.

Answer (score 5):

\begin{align}
\psi (x) &= \int \psi (x') \delta (x-x') dx' \\
&=\int \psi (x') \sum _{n=0}^{\infty} \phi ^{*}_n (x') \phi_n (x) dx' \\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\int \psi (x') \phi ^{*}_n (x') dx'\right) \phi _n(x) \\
&=\sum _{n=0}^{\infty} a_n \phi_n(x) 
\end{align}

You can do this in a basis independent way. Assuming

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}|\phi_n \rangle \langle \phi_n|=I$$

We get:

$$\sum _{n=0}^{\infty}|\phi_n \rangle \langle \phi_n|\psi\rangle =|\psi \rangle $$

Or $$\sum a_n |\phi_n\rangle =|\psi \rangle$$